# How to add an image before a checkbox in Windows form application

Tags: c#, checkbox, treeview

I want to create a checkbox-list wherein I'll have a list of items with checkboxes against them. As I needed a treeview structure, thus I used a Treeview and enabled the checkboxes for them. It's looks like this now:
[image]

All I want now is an image, let's say for **tables** item, the image should be between checkbox and Tables.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do it? Thanks in advance!

**EDITED**

Here's what happening now:
***That's how the tool looks when opened.***

[image]

***But the moment I click on, let's say, Indexes item, the image for it changes with the one below it. ***

[image]

Could you please tell me what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to work with the Imagelist as described here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haf2a2zb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
TreeView1.ImageList = ImageList1
// (Assumes that imageList1 contains at least two images and
// the TreeView control contains a selected image.)
treeView1.SelectedNode.ImageIndex = 0;
treeView1.SelectedNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
```

an ImageList can be added to your form if I am not mistaken end using the designer you can add images to the list.

Comment: Hi @philip, I did as you said. I got what I wanted. Just one thing, clicking on the items is changing the images. I've updated my question to make it more clear.